# How to create "header with load" in MVC Razor layout page?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razorengine

I am trying to create something like a user control in traditional webforms which is to be used in the master page. When it rendered an event is fired to load the data.

How to implement the similar functionality in MVC Razor layout? With my header having its own controller view and model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [@Html.Action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee728618%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) which will let you invoke a controller action and render its respective view.

```
<body>
    @Html.Action("MyAction", "MyController")
</body>
```

where `MyAction` is an action within `MyController` which returns a view.

You can also apply the `ChildActionOnly` attribute to that action to ensure that the only way it can be invoked is through the `Action` method.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [partial view](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/617361/Partial-View-in-ASP-NET-MVC-4).

Partial view is like a regular view with a file extension .cshtml. You can use partial views in a situation where we need a header, footer reused for an MVC web application. You can say that it’s like a user control concept in ASP.NET.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

- `@Html.Action()`- which will call an action of a certain controller and return a view result.
- `@Html.Partial()` - which will generate a partial view